# Netty extreme delay between connection and bytes

Tags: java, netty

I wrote a transparent reverse proxy in Netty, and there appears to be a large amount of delay (about 700ms) between the time after the connection was established, and when the first byte goes through.

```
    b.connect(remoteIp, remotePort).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            ByteBuf buff = future.channel().alloc().buffer();
            if (IS_PING) {
                buff.writeByte(-2);
                buff.writeByte(1);
                buff.writeByte(250);
                writeString(buff, "MC|PingHost");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream flush = new DataOutputStream(bos);
                flush.writeByte(protoVersion);
                writeString(flush, remoteIp);
                flush.writeInt(port);
                buff.writeBytes(bos.toByteArray());
                flush.close();
            } else {
                buff.writeByte(2);
                buff.writeByte(protoVersion);
                writeString(buff, username);
                writeString(buff, host);
                buff.writeInt(port);
            }
            future.channel().writeAndFlush(buff);
            RelayHandler.this.hasConnection = true;
            RelayHandler.this.outboundChannel = future.channel();
        }
```

The delay between the line RelayHandler.this.hasConnection = true and when the first byte from the remote IP comes in is about 600ms

However, when I write a simple "proxy" like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(25565);
    Socket client = socket.accept();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    Socket out = new Socket("5.9.106.20", 25565);
    DataOutputStream outboundDos = new DataOutputStream((out.getOutputStream()));
    DataInputStream outboundDis = new DataInputStream(out.getInputStream());
    while (true) {
        if (dis.available() > 0) {
            byte[] buff = new byte[dis.available()];
            dis.read(buff);
            outboundDos.write(buff);
        }
        if (outboundDis.available() > 0) {
            byte[] buff = new byte[outboundDis.available()];
            outboundDis.read(buff);
            dos.write(buff);
        }
    }
}
```

The delay is unnoticeable - I couldn't even tell that I was routing it at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about delay, but it is better to start writing to a channel after handler's method channelActive() has been called. This will guarantee that the channel is setup and channel's pipeline is constructed and ready.